# Copy files from multiple directories, if their name appears in a list, into a single directory

Tags: terminal, find, cp

I've got a huge tree of folders, each with multiple subdirectories going down around 3 levels. Here's an example with just one level:

```
$ tree
.
|-- AB.txt
|-- CD.txt
|-- destination_folder
|-- spreadsheet.txt
`-- subdirectory
    `-- EF.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

I've got a list of filenames I'm interested in, called `spreadsheet.txt`:

```
$ cat spreadsheet.txt 
AB.txt
CD.txt
EF.txt
```

I'd like to copy all the files which appear in `spreadsheet.txt` into a single folder, e.g. `destination_folder`. Any help very gratefully received! I imagine it will involve `find` and `cp`, but can't seem to work it out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `find` once per filename, and assuming that no filename contain embedded newlines:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p destination_folder || exit 1
while IFS= read -r name; do
    find . -path ./destination_folder -prune -o \
        -type f -name "$name" -exec cp {} destination_folder \;
done <spreadsheet.txt
```

This first creates the destination directory in the current directory (and terminates if that fails).  It then reads the input file, line by line, and calls `find` to locate any regular file that has that name. The destination directory is explicitly avoided by `find` using `-prune` whenever we come across that in our search.

Whenever a file with the correct name is found, it is copied to the destination directory. If multiple files has the same name, the copy in in `destination_folder` will be overwritten.

If the current directory is huge, or if the list of filenames is long (but not many thousands of lines), then this will be a slow operation.  We may therefore choose to do a *single* call to `find`.  The following code assumes that it's executed with e.g. `bash` as it uses arrays:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p destination_folder || exit 1

names=()
while IFS= read -r name; do
    names+=( -o -name "$name" )
done <spreadsheet.txt

find . -path ./destination_folder -prune -o \
    \( "${names[@]:1}" \) -type f -exec cp -t destination_folder {} +
```

Here, I've also chosen to use `cp -t` (a GNU `cp` extension) to be able to call `cp` as few times as possible and not once per found file.

The code above builds an array, `names`, that eventually will be on the correct format for use with `find`. The command that is actually executed at the end of the above code, given the example in your question, will be

```
find . -path ./destination_folder -prune -o '(' -name AB.txt -o -name CD.txt -o -name EF.txt ')' -type f -exec cp -t destination_folder '{}' +
```

To avoid the issue of filename collisions in the destination directory, if you're using GNU `cp` (e.g. on a Linux system), is to use `cp` with its `-b` or `--backup` option.

On non-Linux systems, GNU `cp` may often be available as `gcp` after installing GNU coreutils via a package manager.

---

That last script, but for `/bin/sh` (no arrays):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p destination_folder || exit 1

set --
while IFS= read -r name; do
    set -- -o -name "$name" "$@"
done <spreadsheet.txt

shift

find . -path ./destination_folder -prune -o \
    \( "$@" \) -type f -exec cp -t destination_folder {} +
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure it I'm running it correctly, but all each of the scripts seem to do is create a destination_folder, but not copy any files into it. I'm just copying your code out and pasting  into terminal from the directory containing AB.txt and CD.txt, so not sure if there's something else I should be doing?

Comment: @Mike Thanks, you discovered a bug. I will update! (done now)

Comment: Perfect, that's working well now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop :

```
for filename in $(cat spreadsheet.txt)
do
find . -name "$filename" -exec cp {} /destination/folder \;
done
```